# Flutter image rendering (make the face in the image come into the centre of the container)

Tags: flutter, image

I have a list of images that the user will be selecting. I will then use the images and arrange them in random order with varying width and height.
The problem that happens is that if there is a face it gets hidden or cut out, I want to render the image such that half of the face or the complete face does not get cut out.
Is there any way I can centre the image based on the face in the image in futter.

Comment: Share code and expected output and current outputs pictures for better understanding of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Detecting the face on the image to adjust your image position is not solely Flutter's job, you'll require ML to detect the face on the image, get its position, and then do the adjustment on the Flutter side. But ML solution would be an overkill for this scenario.

I would suggest that while uploading the images, make the user crop them to a square so that while displaying the image nothing will be cut.

Or, you could use [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) package to show complete image without cropping.